# Ubuntu 14.04.2 with kernel version 3.13.0-46-generic fails to shutdown

Tags: shutdown, reboot

When I execute shutdown and restart from the top panel or `sudo shutdown -h`/ `sudo shutdown -r`, everything goes fine until the last line `"Will halt now"`, then it hangs, I've had to hold the power button to shutdown.

I have tried changing

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force'
```

it wont work. If I update the kernel to 3.16, the touchpad wont work then.

Comment: Hard to give you advice other then to give more details. See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Bug_writing_guidelines and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 0):

It depends to your hardware and your Ubuntu vetsion both, so it seams you are using a hardware that is not Ubuntu  certified(http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/).

More information about hardware can help others to solving your problem.

Comment: more hardware info in my bug filed against linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic 3.13.0-46.76 on this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1427947) which can point to more hardware info (lspci)?